# Passing Record id to Apex class using Wire Service from LWC - returned record data not displayed on component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm creating an LWC which is located on a record page. It should display fields of the record for which I am on the record page. The record is from a custom object called Agreement__c.
However, the expected returned data doesn't display on the component.
Here is my code:

The html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Amendment History">
        <div>recordId : {recordId}</div>
        <template if:true={responseReceived}>
            <p>Agreement name: {agreement.Name}</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

The JS:

```
import { wire, api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAgreement from '@salesforce/apex/AgreementManager.getAgreementForId'

export default class DisplayAmendmentHistory extends LightningElement {

    @api
    recordId;
    @wire(getAgreement, {agreementId: '$recordId'}) agreement;

    get responseReceived(){
        if(this.agreement)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The server side controller in Apex:

```
public with sharing class AgreementManager {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Agreement__c getAgreementForId(Id agreementId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Validation_Process__c FROM Agreement__c WHERE Id=:agreementId];
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The return value is in a property called "data", so the template should use:

```
<p>Agreement name: {agreement.data.Name}</p>
```

In addition, you'll want to check if `this.agreement.data` has a value or not.

```
get responseReceived(){
    return !!this.agreement.data; // truthy/falsy to true/false
}
```

But you don't need that check, actually, you can just detect if the data exists directly in the template:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Amendment History">
        <div>recordId : {recordId}</div>
        <p lwc:if={agreement.data}>Agreement name: {agreement.data.Name}</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for the rapid response. I am now getting the following error message:  A Component Error has occurred! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')

Comment: @Fra425 Would you please edit your question to include the new code? I'd be happy to take a look at it for you.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, much appreciated! I found out something that worked. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Fra425 I mean, that works, but if you had 20 properties like this, you'd have nearly 200 lines of code to support those properties. I'd recommend trying to fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by applying @wire to a function (instead of applying it to a property, as I did). The working code is as follows:

In HTML:

```
    <template if:true={agreement}>
        <p>Agreement name: {agreement.Name}</p>
    </template>
```

In JS:

```
    @wire(getAgreement, {agreementId: '$recordId'}) wiredAgreement({data, error}){
    if(data){
        this.agreement = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        console.log(`Data returned: ${JSON.stringify(this.agreement)}`);
    }
    else if(error){
        this.error = error;
        this.agreement = undefined;
    }
};
```